# Safari seems to ignore my DNS Server

Tags: macos, network, safari, dns, big-sur

I am using an Eero Pro 6 device for my home wifi connection.

The "Eero Secure" product offers to let you block certain domains. I have entered "reddit.com" in the block list, and it seems to work:

```
$ nslookup reddit.com
Server:     192.168.4.1
Address:    192.168.4.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   reddit.com
Address: 192.168.4.1
```

192.168.4.1 is my routers IP address, and ends up redirecting to https://blocked.eero.com. All is good here, and this is what I want.

The trouble is that Safari (on my Mac, iPad, and iPhone) seems to find a way around this, and is able to load reddit.com without issue. No amount of `dscacheutil -flushcache`, Develop -> Empty Caches, rebooting, resetting safari, etc - nothing seems to work.

Does anyone have any ideas? Here is my `scutil -dns`:

```
DNS configuration

resolver #1
  nameserver[0] : 192.168.4.1
  if_index : 9 (en0)
  flags    : Request A records
  reach    : 0x00020002 (Reachable,Directly Reachable Address)

resolver #2
  domain   : local
  options  : mdns
  timeout  : 5
  flags    : Request A records
  reach    : 0x00000000 (Not Reachable)
  order    : 300000

resolver #3
  domain   : 254.169.in-addr.arpa
  options  : mdns
  timeout  : 5
  flags    : Request A records
  reach    : 0x00000000 (Not Reachable)
  order    : 300200

resolver #4
  domain   : 8.e.f.ip6.arpa
  options  : mdns
  timeout  : 5
  flags    : Request A records
  reach    : 0x00000000 (Not Reachable)
  order    : 300400

resolver #5
  domain   : 9.e.f.ip6.arpa
  options  : mdns
  timeout  : 5
  flags    : Request A records
  reach    : 0x00000000 (Not Reachable)
  order    : 300600

resolver #6
  domain   : a.e.f.ip6.arpa
  options  : mdns
  timeout  : 5
  flags    : Request A records
  reach    : 0x00000000 (Not Reachable)
  order    : 300800

resolver #7
  domain   : b.e.f.ip6.arpa
  options  : mdns
  timeout  : 5
  flags    : Request A records
  reach    : 0x00000000 (Not Reachable)
  order    : 301000

DNS configuration (for scoped queries)

resolver #1
  nameserver[0] : 192.168.4.1
  if_index : 9 (en0)
  flags    : Scoped, Request A records
  reach    : 0x00020002 (Reachable,Directly Reachable Address)
```

edit: forgot to point out that I am using macOS Big Sur, and iOS/iPadOS 14.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Safari is not doing anything untoward here. My DNS based block for reddit.com worked fine - but not [www.reddit.com](http://www.reddit.com), old.reddit.com (even though the Eero block includes subdomains), and so on. From the command line:

```
$ nslookup www.reddit.com
Server:     192.168.4.1
Address:    192.168.4.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   www.reddit.com
Address: 192.168.4.1
```

Because of that, I expected Safari to resolve [www.reddit.com](http://www.reddit.com) to 192.168.4.1. However, [www.reddit.com](http://www.reddit.com) (and others like old.reddit.com) are actually CNAMEs:

```
$ dig -t cname www.reddit.com
... snipped output ...
;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.reddit.com.     300 IN  CNAME   reddit.map.fastly.net.
```

So, it looks like Safari looks up [www.reddit.com](http://www.reddit.com), sees that it is a CNAME for reddit.map.fastly.net, and then resolves reddit.map.fastly.net and is able to load the page - while displaying [www.reddit.com](http://www.reddit.com) in the URL bar.

I am not saying Safari is doing anything wrong here - this seems like totally reasonable behavior - it was just unexpected to me.

I have now added a DNS block for reddit.map.fastly.net, and everything works as expected.

Comment: Nicely done. I’m bookmarking this as a reminder that web sites call so name DNS lookups, it’s very difficult to pick apart what comes from where.